# Can I link text from a .txt file with other text from another .txt file? C#

Tags: c#

So I'm currently learning C# and one of the exercises from the book I'm reading to learn is to make sort of a dictionary console program in which you can add your own words and definitions. In the code when the user inputs the word and the definition for said word I put each in a different text file. The problem that I have is that when the users looks for a word that he previously added I need the program to print that word with its corresponding definition. So I need the program to know where in the definitions text file the corresponding definition for that word begins and ends, and then print that.

I don't know if this is possible or if there's a better way to get the same result but yeah...

Sorry if I didn't make myself clear I'm just starting to learn :P and sorry if my English isn't the greatest (it's not my native language)

Gonna put the code here (Some of it it's in spanish):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        #region Static variables and stuff

        static string palabra;
        static string definicion;
        static string PalabrasContenido;
        static string DefinicionesContenido;
        static int opcion;

        static bool palabraborrada = false;
        static bool palabraborrada0 = false;

        static FileStream PalabraStream = new FileStream("Palabras.txt", FileMode.Append);
        static FileStream DefinicionStream = new FileStream("Definiciones.txt", FileMode.Append);
        static byte[] PalabraBytes = new byte[100];
        static byte[] DefinicionBytes = new byte[5000];

        //static StreamReader PalabrasSR = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Dani\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication8\\ConsoleApplication8\\bin\\Debug\\Palabras.txt");

        #endregion

        static void ShowMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Por favor escoje tu opcion.");
            Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Agregar palabra.");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Buscar palabra.");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Mostrar palabras.");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Borrar palabra.");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Salir.");
        }

        static void AskChoice()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out opcion);
        }

        static void AddWord()
        {
            PalabrasContenido = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Dani\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication8\\ConsoleApplication8\\bin\\Debug\\Palabras.txt");
            PalabraStream = new FileStream("Palabras.txt", FileMode.Append);
            DefinicionStream = new FileStream("Definiciones.txt", FileMode.Append);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa palabra a agregar...\n");
            palabra = Console.ReadLine().ToLower() + " ";
            Console.WriteLine("");

            if (PalabrasContenido.Contains(palabra))
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n--La palabra '{0}' ya existe en El Diccionario.--\n", palabra);
                Console.WriteLine("Volviendo al menu...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            else
            {               
                Console.WriteLine("Ingresa definicion...\n");
                definicion = Console.ReadLine() + " ";
                Console.WriteLine("");

                PalabraStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(palabra), 0, palabra.Length);

                DefinicionStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(definicion), 0, definicion.Length);

                PalabraStream.Close();
                DefinicionStream.Close();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("--La palabra ha sido agregada con exito--\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Volviendo al menu...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }

        static void SearchWord()
        {
            PalabrasContenido = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Dani\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication8\\ConsoleApplication8\\bin\\Debug\\Palabras.txt");
            DefinicionesContenido = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Dani\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication8\\ConsoleApplication8\\bin\\Debug\\Definiciones.txt");

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingresa palabra a buscar...\n");
            palabra = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (PalabrasContenido.Contains(palabra))
            {
                PalabraStream = new FileStream("Palabras.txt", FileMode.Open);

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\nDefinicion de: {0}", palabra);
                Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________\n");
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", definiciones[palabra]);
                Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Pulsa enter para continuar...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                PalabraStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n--La palabra ingresada no ha sido encontrada--\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Pulsa enter para continuar...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }

        static void ShowWords()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            PalabraStream = new FileStream("Palabras.txt", FileMode.Open);

            if (PalabraStream.Length > 0)
            {        
                Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Palabras encontradas:");
                Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________\n");

                PalabraStream.Read(PalabraBytes, 0, (int)PalabraStream.Length);

                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PalabraBytes));

                PalabraStream.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("\n\nPulsa enter para continuar...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Palabras encontradas:");
                Console.WriteLine("________________________________________________________\n");
                Console.WriteLine("\n--No se han encontrado palabras.--\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Pulsa enter para continuar...");

                PalabraStream.Close();

                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }

        static void DeleteWord()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\nIngresa palabra a borrar...\n");
            palabra = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            palabraborrada = definiciones.Remove(palabra);
            palabraborrada0 = diccionario.Remove(palabra);

            if (palabraborrada == true && palabraborrada0 == true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n--La palabra ha sido borrada con exito.--\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Volviendo al menu...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\n--La palabra no existe.--\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Volviendo al menu...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }

        static void Exit()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n--Gracias por usar El Diccionario.--\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Pulsa enter para continuar...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        static void InvalidInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n--Opcion invalida.--\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Pulsa enter para continuar...\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a Tu diccionario.\n");

            PalabraStream.Close();
            DefinicionStream.Close();

            do
            {
                //Presentar menu y limpiar consola
                Console.Clear();  
                ShowMenu();

                //Pedir opcion
                AskChoice();

                if (opcion == 1)
                {
                    //Añadir palabra
                    AddWord();

                }
                    if (opcion == 2)
                    {
                        //Buscar palabra
                        SearchWord();

                    }

                    if (opcion == 3)
                    {
                        //Mostrar palabras
                        ShowWords();
                    }

                    if (opcion == 4)
                    {
                        DeleteWord();
                    }

                    if (opcion == 5)
                    {
                        Exit();
                    }

                    if (opcion > 5 || opcion < 1)
                    {
                        InvalidInput();
                    }
            } 
            while (opcion != 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I reverted your edit.  If you want to post your new code as a solution, do so properly by posting it as an answer just like anyone else. Editing your **question** to post an **answer** is not appropriate. It's acceptable here to answer your own question - in fact, there's a [help/self-answer] section dedicated to how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can! C# has a great type you can use to work with this, funnily enough it is called a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)!

A dictionary maps something to something else. The thing you are mapping from is called a `key` and the thing your are mapping to is called a `value`. So in your example you are mapping words (keys) to their definitions (values).

So what you need to do is load in both files (as I think you are already doing) and then add them to the dictionary.

An example of how you could load the files into a dictionary and use it is:

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines("Palabras.txt");
string[] definitions = File.ReadAllLines("Definiciones.txt");

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    dictionary.Add(words[i], definitions[i]);
}

string output = dictionary["programmer"]; // "A person who writes computer programs"
```

A few things which may trip you up:

- You need to make sure there is exactly the same number of words as there is definitions in each of the two files
- You can't add the same word twice - keys are unique! You can change the definition associated with the word, or remove the word and re-add it with a new definition - but you can't add a key that is already contained in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks dude, I already knew the dictionary class but I didn't think  I would be able to use it with all of this text file stuff. In the end I had to do much more than just add a dictionary but still :P